# Installing Apache with openSSL

Tags: apache-2.2

Hi I am installing httpd-2.0.63 with the open ssl.
ssl version is OpenSSL 1.0.0a

Commands are :

./configure --prefix=/usr/LBalancer2/apache --enable-so --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/LBalancer2/ssl

make

But this step gives the following ERROR :

ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'ssl_init_ctx_protocol':

ssl_engine_init.c:391: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

ssl_engine_init.c:397: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'ssl_init_ctx_verify':

ssl_engine_init.c:534: error: 'STACK' undeclared (first use in this function)

ssl_engine_init.c:534: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

ssl_engine_init.c:534: error: for each function it appears in.)

ssl_engine_init.c:534: error: expected expression before ')' token

ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'ssl_init_FindCAList':

ssl_engine_init.c:1109: warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression

make[3]: *** [ssl_engine_init.lo] Error 1

make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/arosys/Softwares/httpd-2.0.63/modules/ssl'

make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/arosys/Softwares/httpd-2.0.63/modules/ssl'

make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/arosys/Softwares/httpd-2.0.63/modules'

make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

I have no idea what to do.

Any one can help.

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you're still using Apache httpd 2.0 instead of the 2.2 series?

Comment: No not any reason.the document that I had, gave the url to download apache2.

Answer (score 1):

Apache 2.0/2.2 is not compatible with OpenSSL 1.0.0, see bug reports:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49034
- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47578

You should use OpenSSL 0.9.8.

When it's compiled you will have a module called: mod_ssl.so

You can use ldd to check which library of ssl is used:

```
$ ldd mod_ssl.so
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7f2a000)
libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0xb7eac000)
libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0xb7d59000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7d3f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7be4000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7be0000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb7bcb000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7f2b000)
```

Apache.org has excellent documentation on how to configure your webserver: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Comment: I installed OpenSSL 0.9.8. It installed. How can I make sure that Apache is installed with OpenSSL.

Comment: this time also I used the same configure command but moved from apache2.0 to apache2.2

Comment: The options you used before: --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/the/location/of/openssl-0.9.8 should do just that.

Comment: Isnt any command or file's presence that can make sure?
one more thing how can I apply security provided by openssl.Any useful refrence?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is missing headers for openssl are you sure they exit in /usr/LBalancer2/ssl check your output of the configure command to make sure that the openssl headers are picked up.

Comment: sure there was no problem in configure command.

Comment: there was problem of missing header while installing opennssl.But that was solved by googling.